# How would I always select the last JSON object from an API call?

Tags: javascript, json

So I'm still relatively new to JavaScript. Maybe a few times a month I try to mess around and practice some stuff if I'm not too busy.

I've been into stocks for quite awhile and I've seen there are some pretty decent free APIs out there for market data. I figured it would be a decent time to fool around again and maybe learn something (and if so, hopefully retain it).

I'm using the Alpha Vantage API from (https://www.alphavantage.co/) and it returns a JSON with a decent amount of data (here is a demo JSON from their site so you have an idea of what my call returns(I use the 1min interval, their demo uses 5min but that's not important): https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo ).

I'd like to select the last (most recent date/time) object in the "Time Series (Xmin)" object so I can use the updated data that is within the most recent date object.

I have tried a few different solutions I've seen online for selecting the last item in an array/object but since I'm such a noob, I'm sure that I'm missing out on something really simple. Or maybe I'm not going about this in the correct way at all. (I even wasted an hour trying to format the return from the JS builtin date methods to match the API call date format "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS" and just use that to somehow select the one that matches in the JSON but it did not work out for me in the end and then I thought why wouldn't I just try to select the last object. ...it is late...)

```
fetch(api)
          .then(response => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data["Time Series (1min)"]);
            let dataProvided = data["Time Series (1min)"];

            //my attempt to select the last 'date' (for example 2019-07-26 16:00:00 would be the last one as of friday)
            //this returns undefined when console.log
            dataProvidedRecentDate = dataProvided[dataProvided.length - 1];

            //undefined
            console.log(dataProvidedRecentDate);

            //this is manually just to see... (not my goal obviously)
            dataProvidedSpecificDate = dataProvided["2019-07-26 16:00:00"];
            dataProvidedVolume = dataProvidedSpecificDate["5. volume"];



            let changeData = document.querySelector('.test_three');
            changeData.textContent = dataProvidedVolume;
```

Instead of logging the last (most recent) date object. I am getting `undefined`. I have tried a slice method I've seen elsewhere online and it did not work either. My end goal here, if you couldn't have guessed, would be to display the data within the most recent date object to be displayed on the page (ex. Volume, Open, Close, High, Low). Any help is much appreciated, I'd be excited to see what I'm doing wrong because I've been pullin my hair out. Thank you!

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: A parameter for that function. It could have been anything, I just choose data.

Comment: No, what is an example of the value contained within `data`?

Comment: It's the returned data from the API call. Almost identical to this https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo

Comment: Object.keys(data["Time Series (1min)"])[0]

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't notice, but the most recent data is the first property of the object and not the last. There isn't a builtin method to access the first property on an object but you could use a `for..in` loop. `for..in` is bascially an iterator to iterate over an objects property.
You could do something like this

```
let recent;
for(recent in data["Time Series (5min)"])break;
```

This would store the key of the first item of `data["Time Series (5min)"]` in `recent` and then break the loop.
You now have the key to the first item, and to access its value a simple bracket notation would do.
`data["Time Series (5min)"][recent]`

Comment: Oh my goodness. Wow I need sleep. I guess it is because in chrome dev console, when I open the object the most recent date is at the bottom. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `"3. Last Refreshed"` value can be used as key to get the latest object :

```js
var data = {
  "Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-07-26 16:00:00", // use this value as key
    "4. Interval": "5min",
    "5. Output Size": "Full size",
    "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
  },
  "Time Series (5min)": {
    "2019-07-26 16:00:00": {
      "1. open": "141.6000",
      "2. high": "141.6500",
      "3. low": "141.3000",
      "4. close": "141.3300",
      "5. volume": "854096"
    },
    "2019-07-26 15:55:00": {
      "1. open": "141.5900",
      "2. high": "141.6750",
      "3. low": "141.5750",
      "4. close": "141.5950",
      "5. volume": "400982"
    }
  }
}

var last = data["Meta Data"]["3. Last Refreshed"]

console.log( last, data["Time Series (5min)"][last] )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are expecting `data["Time Series (1min)"]` to an array but infact it isn't. It contains properites not objects. So now you have to find the last property of your object. `Object.keys()` may give you all the keys an object contains as an array. So you may use this and get the last item in the array. Here is the code sample to explain this.

```
// Verify we got the expected data.
if (data != null && data["Time Series (5min)"] != null) {
    // Get all properties as an array.
    var enteries = Object.keys(data["Time Series (5min)"]);

    // Get last key from an array.
    var lastEntry = enteries[enteries.length - 1];

    console.log("Last entry key name is \"" + lastEntry + "\"");
}
```